# Knockout.js -> Change descendant binding in foreach

Tags: javascript, foreach, knockout.js

Say I have a counter `count = 2`. For each count, I want

```
<div>
    </div></div>
</div>
```

all of which will have bindings to another view model, of which, count is not a part. Is there no way apart from dumping all the VM specific code in one giant VM?

Comment: You don't have a lot of information here, just a general question. The best you can hope for is a general answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing stopping you breaking your viewmodel up..... rather than 1 giant VM you have 1 root VM.  Which then contains objects that relate to different parts of your view

Comment: Sometimes, a general answer answers everything. Tx Keith